# How do I extract results after joining multiple tables in the following schema?

Tags: mysql, sql

I've used the following commands for creating the tables.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer(
custid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
fname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
lname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
mno varchar(10),
password varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (custid)
);

CREATE TABLE Employee(
empid int NOT NULL,
fname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
lname varchar(30) NOT NULL,
mno varchar(10),
password varchar(30),
PRIMARY KEY (empid)
);

CREATE TABLE Address(
id int NOT NULL,
street varchar(30),
doorno varchar(30),
city varchar(30),
statee varchar(30),
zip varchar(5),
county varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Customer (custid)
);

CREATE TABLE EmpAddress(
id int NOT NULL,
street varchar(30),
doorno varchar(30),
city varchar(30),
statee varchar(30),
zip varchar(5),
county varchar(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES Employee (empid)
);

CREATE TABLE Service(
serviceid int NOT NULL,
serviceType varchar(30),
amount int,
PRIMARY KEY (serviceid)
);

CREATE TABLE Booking(
bookingid int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
empid int NOT NULL,
custid int NOT NULL,
serviceid int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (bookingid),
FOREIGN KEY (empid) REFERENCES Employee (empid),
FOREIGN KEY (custid) REFERENCES Customer (custid),
FOREIGN KEY (serviceid) REFERENCES Service (serviceid)
);

CREATE TABLE Availability(
empid int NOT NULL,
datee date NOT NULL,
startTime int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (empid, datee, startTime),
FOREIGN KEY (empid) REFERENCES Employee (empid)
);

CREATE TABLE Transactions(
bookingid int NOT NULL,
paymentMethod varchar(20),
serviceid int,
amount int,
PRIMARY KEY (bookingid),
FOREIGN KEY (bookingid) REFERENCES Booking (bookingid),
FOREIGN KEY (serviceid) REFERENCES Service (serviceid)
);
```

I am trying to write a query that returns the bookingid, firstName, lastName, street, door no, zip code, serviceType, date and startTime GIVEN empid.

It is essentially a join of 5 tables and I'd implemented the query as:

```
SELECT B.bookingid, C.fname, C.lname, AD.street,
AD.doorno, AD.zip,S.serviceType, A.datee, A.startTime
FROM booking as B, availability as A, customer as C, 
address as AD, Service as   S 
WHERE
B.empid=501 AND B.custid=C.custid 
AND C.custid=AD.id 
AND  B.serviceid=S.serviceid AND B.empid=A.empid;
```

The REQUIRED results should have been:

```
BookingID  fname  lname  street  doorno  zipcode  serviceType  date          starttime
   1        X       Y     ABC      33      5335      Clean    2015-05-20    9
   2        P       Q     NMO      55      8294      Shift    2015-06-11    11
```

But the results give me the cross product of tables:

```
BookingID  fname  lname  street  doorno  zipcode  serviceType  date      starttime
   1        X       Y     ABC      33      5335      Clean    2015-05-20    9
   1        X       Y     ABC      33      5335      Shift    2015-06-11    11
   2        P       Q     NMO      55      8294      Clean    2015-05-20    9 
   2        P       Q     NMO      55      8294      Shift    2015-06-11    11
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my query.

Comment: you are getting it coz of `servicetype` column they are having different values. you want top 1 row for booking id 1 and 2 and so on ?

Comment: Not really. For each booking id , there should be only one record. There are only three serviceTypes (Clean,Shift and Plumb), and each bookingID is associated with only one serviceType.

Comment: The primary key for Availability is `(empid, datee, startTime)` yet you are joining just on `Booking.empid` - it is possible there is more than one availability row per Employee. You may e.g. need to add a Timestamp to booking and interpolate on date. I can't however see how ServiceType would be different for the same booking.

Comment: Thanks Stuart. I think you are right. I am not completely sure how to modify the query though. Could you please give the modified query so that I may understand it more clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary key for Availability is currently `(empid, datee, startTime)`, yet the JOIN is done on just on `Booking.empid` - it is possible there is more than one availability row per Employee.

I believe you will need to add a timestamp to `Booking` and interpolate on date during the join to `Availability`:

```
CREATE TABLE Booking(
   -- ...
   bookingDate datetime NOT NULL,
   -- ...
);
```

I would also suggest that you add and end datetime bounds to the Availability, and store Date and Time as one (otherwise you will need to continually add the time back in):

```
CREATE TABLE Availability(
   -- ...
  startDateTime datetime NOT NULL,
  endDateTime datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (empid, startDateTime), -- Put some rules to prevent overlap
);
```

The query then interpolates Booking to Availability on Date and Time:

```
SELECT B.bookingid, C.fname, C.lname, AD.street, AD.doorno, AD.zip,
       S.serviceType, A.startDateTime
FROM 
   booking as B
   INNER JOIN customer as C
     ON B.custid=C.custid 
   INNER JOIN availability as A
     ON B.empid=A.empid AND b.bookingDate BETWEEN A.startDateTime AND A.endDateTime
   INNER JOIN address as AD
     ON C.custid=AD.id 
   INNER JOIN Service as S
     ON B.serviceid=S.serviceid
WHERE
  B.empid=501;
```

I've also adjusted the join to use `JOIN ON` rather than doing the join in the `WHERE`.

This would address the duplicated availability data. However, I can't see how `ServiceType` would be different for the same booking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DISTINCT` to eliminate duplicate records. Also always try to use explicit joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT B.bookingid, C.fname, C.lname, AD.street,
                AD.doorno, AD.zip,S.serviceType, A.datee, A.startTime
FROM booking as B
INNER JOIN availability as A ON B.empid = A.empid
INNER JOIN customer as C ON B.custid = C.custid
INNER JOIN address as AD ON C.custid = AD.id
INNER JOIN Service as S ON B.serviceid = S.serviceid
WHERE B.empid = 501
```